# PA Learners Permit - Nightime Driving with Parents

Tags: driving, minor, pennsylvania

I am a teen driver (still sixteen) with a Pennsylvania learners permits, and my parents and I are unsure of something. I am required so many nighttime driving hours, however, if I understand correctly, I am not permitted to drive between eleven in the afternoon through five in the morning. Is that correct? When would ‘night driving’ be considered then? Since I only have a learners permit, I always have my parent in the passenger seat anyways. What would proper procedure be if I was driving, with my parents of course, and ten passed. Let’s assume we were on some long road (traveling to a destination, instead of driving just for experience) and there’s not somewhere to pull over, or at least for some period time. For example, if we were on a long desolate country road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pennsylvania classifies nighttime driving as between sunset and sunrise. Between 11 p.m. and 5 a.m., a ["young driver"](https://www.penndot.gov/TravelInPA/Safety/TrafficSafetyAndDriverTopics/Pages/Young-Driver.aspx) is not allowed to drive unless it's for employment, charity, or volunteer work and you should have documentation about what you're doing.

Honestly, if your parent is in the car, I think it's likely that a police office would give you a warning, but even a desolate country road will have a driveway, a crossroad, or some other location where you can pull over and change drivers.

I found a AAA site that said the 11 p.m. - 5 a.m. restriction was that you must have an over-18 **family member** with you rather than anyone over 18. It's possible that relaxed restriction is on a junior or senior license rather than a learner's permit.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. That's what I had thought, but neither my parents nor I were sure and better safe then sorry. Of course, the ladder was added more as an afterthought as a theatrical more than a practical question. Thanks for the response.